# Use patched npm package in another project

Tags: react-native, npm, node-modules, patch

I installed an NPM package for my React Native app and modified it as suitable. Then I created a patch for that module. Now I want to use that same modified package on another application. How can I do it locally without updating it as an issue on Github?

Comment: You can just install the NPM package and copy the patch files to another project